# AJAX GET request going to error despite getting the response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, get

I've set up a GET request to retrieve some JSON from an API for my website. It keeps going to an Error despite showing the response correctly in the network tab of the Console and a 200 status (pictures attached). I've run the JSON response through a validator and it checks out fine. What is the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    bindProject();
});

function bindProject() {
    $(".project-link").on("click.project", function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var $this = $(this);

        loadProject(id, function() {
            $("#previous, #next").show();
        })
    });
}

function loadProject(id, callback) {
    $.get(BASE + "api/page/projects/" + id, {}, function(data) {
        if (data.success == "true") {
            console.log("success");
            $("#project-info").attr("projectid", id);
            $("#project-title").html(data.title);
            $("#project-info").html(data.info);
            $("#project-year").html(data.info);
            $("#project-tags").html(data.tags);
            setProject();
        else {
            console.log("error")
        }
    }, "json")
}
```

[200 STATUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUzHn.png)

[JSON RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhKLe.png)

Comment: you mean it does the console.log('error') or.... ?

Comment: Also something to note, you are including the "json" on the request.  Meaning the response MUST return valid json, even if it is just an empty object or array.  Returning invalid json, or no json at all, will cause $.get to go to the error handling because it could not parse correctly as expected.

Comment: You probably do not have a "success" `key` with a "true" `value` in `data`. That is why. The whole `function()` you provide only executes on success... Because this is the success callback. You don't need to check if the request is successful. Look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Yes. It does console.log("error"). The response that I got in in the Network tab of the console passes a JSON validator test, is this adequate to determine whether the JSON is causing the Error?

Comment: Just to precise my previous comment... If you want to test if the request is successful and provide a callback, use @R. Bock answer. Because what you actually do is to check if the "success" key in your json has a "true" value... Which is obviously not the right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for help and taking the time to help @LouysPatriceBessette, I really appreciate it. You were correct, the success `key` did did not have a "true" `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `data` have an attribute `success`? If what you're trying to do is check if the connection was successful, you could use:

```
$.get( BASE + "api/page/projects/" + id, function(data) {
    alert( "success" );
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert( "second success" );
        // handle success case here
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        alert( "error" );
        // handle error case here
    });
```

More information [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Hope it helps.

Comment: You were correct, I didn't have a "success" `key` that was set to `true`. Thank you for taking the time to write a check for the connection, I will use it in the future,